# How does LB maps response to the actual client request

Tags: amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, system-design

I'm preparing for system design interviews and don't have much hands-on experience with load balancers. There are a few questions that have been bugging me for a long time, so I'm just hoping for responses from the wonderful community.

How does LB map the response to the client's real request?

*I believe that some mapping should be kept at LB which helps to send it back to client.*

Flow should be - based on my limited understanding and the assumptions made above.

> 1. Client(C) sends request
>
> | Source IP | Target IP | Request Identifier | Request |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10.11.11.12 | 15.12.14.74 (LB address ) | R1 | /getUsers |
>
> 2. LB will forward this to Server
>
> | Source IP | Target IP | Request Identifier | Request > |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 15.12.14.74 (LB address ) | 115.12.14.80(Server Address) | R1 | /getUsers |
>
> 3. server will respond back the request,
>
> | Source IP | Target IP | Request Identifier | Response |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 15.12.14.80(Server Address) | 15.12.14.74 (LB address ) | R1 | [Users] |
>
> 4. LB will map it using "Request Identifier" and will send it back to client
>
> | Source IP | Target IP | Response |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 15.12.14.74 (LB address ) | 10.11.11.12 | [Users] |

Answer (score 1):

The key, which is missing in your questions, is ports. Load balancers are, so called, operating on either L4 or L7 levels. Basically, the lowest they do is L4, which is transport layer.

L3 is the network layers, and IP protocol lives there. TCP is L4 and the difference to L3 is in ports.

So when a client A talks to server B - the request (L4) has both ip addresses and ports - tuples. For example, client's side will look like [10.11.11.12, 10023(random port above 1024)] and server side will be [15.12.14.74, 80] - the same tuple exists on the other side, where the LB connects to actual server, but in that case the LB plays client's role.

With ports in mind, LB have a mapping between connections it received from clients and connections LB established to servers. Having ports allow many to many mapping - same client may have more than one connection to many servers via LB.

The above was about L4; L7 works in similar way - just more processing is happening on the load balancer itself.